# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sin^\beta\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + 1} d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Mathematica can't do it, any work around?

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sin^\beta\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + 1} d\theta, \qquad\qquad \beta>0.$$

Comment: What is the range of $\beta$ that you consider? Integer, positive, and real number?..

Comment: $\beta$ is any positive number

Comment: is it $\sin^\beta\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$ or $\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)^\beta$? I mean inside the sine or outside it?

Comment: It's $\sin^\beta (\frac{\theta}{2})$

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be intractable even with advanced techniques. Formally (and not hard to justify), you can expand the integrand into a geometric series, assuming $\beta > 0$:
$$
\frac{1}{(\sin\theta/2))^\beta + 1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n (\sin \theta / 2)^{n \beta} 
$$
Each term can be integrated, 
$$
\int_0^\pi (\sin \theta / 2)^{n \beta}  d \theta =\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2} (\beta n+1)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\beta
   n}{2}+1\right)}
$$
Now for even $\beta = 2k$ the sum is 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2} (\beta n+1)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\beta
   n}{2}+1\right)} = \pi \cdot \, _k F_{k-1}(\frac{1}{\beta}, \frac{3}{\beta},\dots, \frac{\beta-1}{\beta}, \frac{2}{\beta}, \frac{4}{\beta}, \dots, \frac{\beta - 2}{\beta}; -1)
$$
that is a generalized hypergeometric function with a number of parameters that depends on $\beta$. It's unclear how to write this for general  $\beta$.

Comment: I'm sorry. Since OP just answered my question, please just ignore my question above.